# export default in JavaScript confusion

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
       // aoo.js 
        const c =950;
        function hello(){
           console.log(c);
           }
          export default hello;
     // moo.js 
        import q from './aoo';
         console.log(q());
```

How it is fetching variable c value in 
            "moo.js"  ,even though we are not exporting it?

Comment: Your confusion seems more related to what a function is than to import/export

Comment: If you had to export (and presumably also import) all the internal dependencies of your dependencies, you'd be doing nothing else all day but track down internal implementation details…

Comment: The QA chosen for closure is perfect here.